# What does *(int*) mean in C++?

Tags: c++, opengl

I encountered the following line in a OpenGL tutorial and I wanna know what does the `*(int*)` mean and what is its value

```
if ( *(int*)&(header[0x1E])!=0  )
```

Comment: It's casting the address of `header[0xe1]` to a pointer-to-`int` then dereferences that pointer. Google "C type casting".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's take this a step at a time:

```
header[0x1E]
```

`header` must be an array of some kind, and here we are getting a reference to the `0x1E`th element in the array.

```
&(header[0x1E])
```

We take the address of that element.

```
(int*)&(header[0x1E])
```

We cast that address to a pointer-to-int.

```
*(int*)&(header[0x1E])
```

We dereference that pointer-to-int, yielding an `int` by interpreting the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of `header`, starting at offset `0x1E`, as an `int` and gets the value it finds there.

```
if ( *(int*)&(header[0x1E])!=0  )
```

It compares that resulting value to `0` and if it isn't `0`, executes whatever is in the body of the `if` statement.

Note that this is potentially very dangerous.  Consider what would happen if `header` were declared as:

```
double header [0xFF];
```

...or as:

```
int header [5];
```

Comment: ... which interprets the first `sizeof(int)` bytes of `header`, starting at offset `0x1E`, as an `int` and gets the value.

Comment: @templatetypedef: "first" probably isn't a good description of "starting at offset `0x1E`", but yes I believe that's the more meaningful explanation.

Comment: @templatetypedef:  Agreed and updated.  Hope you don't mind I used your words.

Comment: Additionally, since it is type aliasing, either the C++ implementation being used must support type aliasing or it might not get the current bytes in `header[0x1E]` at all.

Comment: Most worrying, on many systems integers are 4 byte aligned, and `0x1E` is not a multiple of 4. This is the sort of x86 code that fails on ARM.

Answer (score 6):

It's truly a terrible piece of code, but what it's doing is:

```
&(header[0x1E])
```

takes the address of the (`0x1E + 1`)th element of array `header`, let's call it `addr`:

```
(int *)addr
```

C-style cast this address into a pointer to an `int`, let's call this pointer p:

```
*p
```

dereferences this memory location as an `int`.

Comment: "It's truly a terrible piece of code". I think this should be mentioned in a good answer to this question. +1 (not only for that of course).

Comment: How would you write this code? `header` is (I presume) the header of a BMP file stored in a char buffer; the 4-byte little-endian integer field starting at byte offset 0x1E is the compression method (0 meaning uncompressed).

Comment: @rici, one could declare `header` struct then cast pointer to the beginning of data to the pointer to that struct.

Comment: @n0rd: You could do that, but you'd have to arrange for your struct to have a non-aligned four-byte integer at offset 0x1E, which would also be ugly and non-portable.

Comment: @rici, talking about portability: this cast is not much more portable than my. Unaligned read (and reading from offset of `0x1E` is quite probably unalighned) can either fail, or produce unexpected results on most platforms other than IA-32 and amd64.

Comment: So, really good thing to do would be deserialize properly, but it seems a bit overkill for reading one field. Another option would be `memcpy` to int variable: that'll deal with unaligned read.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming header is an array of bytes, and the original code has been tested only on intel, it's equivalent with:

header[0x1E] + header[0x1F] << 8 + header[0x20] << 16 + header[0x21] << 24;

However, besides the potential alignment issues the other posters mentioned, it has at least two more portability problems:

- on a platform with 64 bit ints, it will make an int out of bytes 0x1E to 0x25 instead of the above; it will be also wrong on a platform with 16 bit ints, but I suppose those are too old to matter
- on a big endian platform the number will be wrong, because the bytes will get reversed and it will end up as:

header[0x1E] << 24 + header[0x1F] << 16 + header[0x20] << 8 + header[0x21];

Also, if it's a bmp file header as rici assumed, the field is probably unsigned and the cast is done to a signed int. In this case it doesn't matter as it's being compared to zero, but in some other case it may.